# summing up two preg_match_all into one

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Extracting from `$fm` into `$parts` all `sum(anything)`:

```
preg_match_all('/sum\((.*?)\)/i', $fm, $parts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

How to extract `avg(anything)` from `$fm` into the same `$parts`? 
Where do I need to insert the `OR`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:sum|avg)\((.*?)\)/i', $fm, $parts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Note the `:?` is to prevent that part of the match from being returned as you do not want it to be . It basically means disregard these parentheses as they are not meant to be capturing parentheses but just a list of possible matches to search for.